# How Change the style of the error message

Tags: symfony

I use Symfony 5.4 in php7.4 and no framework for the css

When I want to use the "UniqueEntity" in order to have an error message if I have twice the same email, I can't find a way to change the style of the message, I would like to know if it was possible to put it in a class or something like that plz

I can do in css :

```
#register > ul > li {}
```

But i think it's not a good practice

[HTML img and render of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omtmA.png)

Comment: You change it with css. If you don't include a framework or custom stylesheets, you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: Personally, I like the approach [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/) takes with regard to `is-valid/is-invalid` and `valid-feedback/invaild-feedback`, although I don't know how they setup the automated show/hide when the class is added to the field.

Comment: I would like to change it to personal css but I would like it to be in a div for example
Except that since I use {{ form_widget(form) }} in twig the message puts itself in my form by creating an ul and a li, not in a personal div

I can't use boostrap for this project unfortunaly :/

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, there's more to twig form functionality than that. Try https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Yes i can do like this but i have to change form_widget to many form_row, there is no other way for do the same without have to repeat form_row ? 
Thx for all your answers

Comment: I don't think you can cherry pick `form_error()` without replicating the other parts of `form_widget()` at that level. I'm not an expert, though, so somebody else may have an idea.

Comment: I will do like you said, it work so thx and if someone have another answer i hear you :)